# Error configuring Workflow 1.0 on Sharepoint 2013

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server, installation, workflow-manager

I'm new to SharePoint so I may not be clear in my wording (terminology and all).  I'm trying to get an on-premise installation of SharePoint 2013 Server.  I've successfully installed SharePoint, set up a development site, and have a working SharePoint hosted/client-side running app (all jQuery).

I've installed Workflow 1.0 for SharePoint 2013 successfully, but have run into an error I can't seem to make heads or tails on trying to configure it.  The service account specified appears to have the proper permissions and appears to be valid, but not sure where to look moving forward.  There's so much information my eyes are glossing over.

Thank you for any pointed direction that can be offered.

Below is my error:

> [Error] [3/6/2015 12:41:01 PM]:
>   System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: Could not
>   obtain information about Windows NT group/user '', error code
>   0x5. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not obtain
>   information about Windows NT group/user '', error code 0x5.
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)    at

Comment: Is the service account a local service account or a domain-based service account?

Comment: I was originally a local account, but changed it to a domain account in the course of trying to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, This error is because SQL Server is not able to obtain information about the specified account.

Either  You run the SQL Server Instance as a local user or The SQL Server instance account is not **privileged to read the Active Directory**.

To fix the issue.

- Try to change the SQL server instance account to some other account during the WF manager Installation, once completed then change account again.
- Try to Install the WF manager using the SQL account.
- [Another way is add the SQL Server service account](http://consulting.risualblogs.com/blog/2013/03/01/could-not-obtain-information-about-windows-nt-groupuser-domainuser-error-code-0x5-sqlstate-42000-error-15404-connisloginsysadmin/) to the ‘BUILTIN\Windows Authorization Access Group’ on your DC. You can then run “EXECUTE AS USER = ‘domain\user’” on SQL Server to check.

Answer (score 0):

I've this problem too and solved this way

1. Go to "SQL SERVER Configuration Manger"
2. In left pan select "SQL Server Services"
3. In Right pan Right click on "SQL SERVEr" on choose properties
4. In "Log on" tab ENter user that enter in `"Workflow manager configuration wizard"` (my perviuos user was local administrator of SQL server)

Done,